Date and time range filter in SQL
I have this data
2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399
2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570
2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320
2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434
2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837
2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006
2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343
2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399
2024-09-13 15:07:42.3220570
2024-09-13 12:09:54.2842320
2024-09-13 13:14:46.4739434
2024-09-13 14:16:34.7590837
2024-09-14 17:25:54.0899006
2024-09-14 18:21:27.6672343

and I want to filter by a specific date and time separately.
This is my query
SELECT [r].[CreateDate]
FROM [Runners] AS [r]
WHERE CONVERT(date, [r].[CreateDate]) >= '2024-09-13'
AND CONVERT(date, [r].[CreateDate]) <= '2024-09-14'
AND CONVERT(time, [r].[CreateDate]) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '02:00:00'
ORDER BY CreateDate

If I comment time filter query return result
but I need this range 20:00 - 02:00 am, I know 20:00 is greater than 2:00 The problem is this and I don't need 19:00 , 18:00 , ...
.Please keep in mind that time range is dynamic
For example, it can be 15:00 - 18:00 and... etc
How can I fix it?

"The problem is this and i don't need 21:00 , 18:00 " Do you want 21:00 or not ?

@Squirrel sorry i updated my question

@DaleK I need exactly the same data to be received in the output, but this query does not return anything

BETWEEN assumes the lower end of the range is on the left of the AND. Compare the results of SELECT 1 WHERE 19 BETWEEN 20 AND 2; and SELECT 1 WHERE 19 BETWEEN 2 AND 20;

i added more data i don't need

@AlwaysLearning I know this and I mentioned it in my question

So have you tried a simple datetime range, then? e.g.: WHERE r.[CreateDate] BETWEEN '2024-09-13T20:00:00' AND '2024-09-14T02:00:00' If you're only looking for events between 20:00:00 and 02:00:00 across multiple days then you probably need to split the time range in two - before and after midnight.

Try to break your time range into 2 parts : 1st from 20:00:00 to 23:59:59 and 2nd from 00:00:00 to 02:00:00 like this .... Where( ( CONVERT(date, [r].[CreateDate]) ='2024-09-13' and (CONVERT(time, [r].[createDate]) between 1st range) or ( CONVERT(date, [r].[CreateDate]) ='2024-09-14' and (CONVERT(time, [r].[createDate]) between 2st range)

@AlwaysLearning Please post an answer with an example so that it can be understood and return exactly the result I want thanks

@jack so you say its dynamic, does the client provide you with a date separate from the time? Or a datetime? Please show exactly what the inputs from your client app are.

@jack As I said, please show it in your question, exactly what inputs come from the client. I'm not going to update my answer again and run the risk of it not doing precisely what you need.

@jack as in, add SQL variables to your query to show which values are received and how they are used.

Tag: [sql] says: " Questions should include ...., table structure, .....".   Is your field CreateDate a DATE or a DATETIME ?   Possible duplicate with Datetime BETWEEN statement not working in SQL Server

Can you [edit] your question ans make clear what your desired result is?   (And why it is different than this: https://dbfiddle.uk/hC9ZgjXZ   ?)

@Luuk that result is the same as the accepted answer isn't it?

As a side note: You should consider if you want your date/time ranges to be inclusive on both ends. If you had a query for the range 20:00 to 02:00 and another for the range 02:00 to 20:00, would you want the boundary times 02:00 and 20:00 to be included in both results? Often you want a half-open interval, where the range is >= @StartTime and < @EndTime (not <=). If this is just a user initiated query for display, you probably don't care. But if this is a batch process sending out payments, you do want to make sure you don't send out the same payment twice.

... Also, avoid any logic that uses boundary conditions like 23:59, 23:59:59, 23:59:59.997, or 23:59:59.9999999 (as was suggested in one of the earlier comments). They are imprecise.

One more question to ask yourself: Would the query ever need to include the entire 24-hour time range?

You can do something like this:
DECLARE @fromdate date = '20240913'
, @todate date = '20240914'
, @fromtime time = '20:00:00'
, @totime time = '02:00:00'

;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT    CreateDate
  FROM  (
    VALUES
    ('2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399'),
    ('2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570'),
    ('2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320'),
    ('2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434'),
    ('2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837'),
    ('2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006'),
    ('2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343'),
    ('2024-09-13 15:07:42.3220570'),
    ('2024-09-13 12:09:54.2842320'),
    ('2024-09-13 13:14:46.4739434'),
    ('2024-09-13 14:16:34.7590837'),
    ('2024-09-14 17:25:54.0899006'),
    ('2024-09-14 18:21:27.6672343')
  ) x (CreateDate)
)
SELECT  [r].[CreateDate]
FROM    cte AS [r]
WHERE   CONVERT(date, [r].[CreateDate]) >= @fromdate
AND CONVERT(date, [r].[CreateDate]) <= @todate
AND CASE 
        WHEN @fromtime < @totime THEN IIF(CONVERT(time, r.createDate) BETWEEN @fromtime AND @totime, 1, 0)
        ELSE IIF(CONVERT(time, r.createDate) NOT BETWEEN @totime AND @fromtime , 1, 0)
    END = 1
ORDER BY CreateDate;

If fromtime is less than totime, you can do a regular BETWEEN from and to query.
If fromtime is > than totime, you reverse the logic and check so that the time is not between TO and FROM time.
Note that if you want exclusive ranges (ie. 20:00 - 02:00 should not match 20:00), you have to change between to > and <, exercise to fix that is left for the reader.
Output:



CreateDate




2024-09-13 00:07:42.3220570


2024-09-13 00:09:54.2842320


2024-09-13 00:14:46.4739434


2024-09-13 00:16:34.7590837


2024-09-13 20:00:50.1319399


2024-09-14 00:25:54.0899006


2024-09-14 01:21:27.6672343




Come on man... I was trying to get OP to clarify and you just gave it to them. Of course I have this waiting in the wings.

Sorry, i was kind of in a hurry to get the weekend started :D It didn't look like his explanation was forthcoming all too quickly either

Exactly, so if no explanation is coming, neither should an answer.

@siggemannen Thank you for just posting the answer without inconvenience. I know that on stackoverflow there are professional developers who are only looking to solve other people's problems, not inconvenience  because time is really valuable. Have a nice weekend.

@DaleK Don't tell me that you didn't know the answer because your answer was very simple and unprofessional, if you didn't want to answer, you didn't send it. It's better to say I didn't know :)

@jack the lesson here is, ask a clear question right from the start and you'll get a clear answer quickly.

@jack Please take care to do not write unkind comments. Dale's answer was not unprofessional, it was just correct and answered the question you asked. If the answer was not sufficient in your opinion, that's because of your vague question that really should be improved.

Note that there are subtle differences in the BETWEEN vs NOT BETWEEN conditions in the time-range checks - BETWEEN is inclusive, while NOT BETWEEN is exclusive.

A critical skill for a SQL developer is Logical Operators e.g. AND, OR, NOT, XOR.
Then approaching the problem from this perspective combined with the tools available one can express the problem as follows:

If the EndTime is greater than the StartTime then the value under test must satisfy both conditions for which we use AND

CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) >= @StartTime AND CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) <= @EndTime

This can then be simplified using BETWEEN to
CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime


But if the StartTime is greater than the EndTime then the value under test only needs to satisfy one condition, because inherently if its greater than the StartTime then is valid until the end of the day, and the same with the EndDate its valid from the start of the day. So here we use OR

CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) >= @StartTime OR CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) <= @EndTime

This can also be simplified using BETWEEN (reversing and negating the condition) to
CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) NOT BETWEEN @EndTime AND @StartTime

Putting it all together gives
WHERE CONVERT(date, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND (
  (
    @EndTime < @StartTime
    AND CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) NOT BETWEEN @EndTime AND @StartTime  
  )
  OR (
    @EndTime >= @StartTime
    AND CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime  
  )
)

Example using your data
Hopefully this provides some useful skills for solving future logic based problems.
Note: The accepted answer is still implementing this logic. There are often many ways to implement such logic, but the first step is always being clear what the logic is. Then one may optimise that using the tools available.
Addendum as rightly pointed out by @TN BETWEEN is inclusive and therefore NOT BETWEEN doesn't meet the criteria assuming an inclusive criteria. Therefore the consistent inclusive solution is:
WHERE CONVERT(date, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND (
  (
    @EndTime < @StartTime
    AND (
      CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) >= @StartTime
      OR CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) <= @EndTime
    )
  )
  OR (
    @EndTime >= @StartTime
    AND CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime  
  )
)

And as @TN also points out this doesn't account for a 24 hour period. The following might work as you require where if the StartTime is the same as the EndTime it just returns all rows in the date window.
WHERE CONVERT(date, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND (
  @EndTime = @StartTime
  OR (
    @EndTime < @StartTime
    AND (
      CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) >= @StartTime
      OR CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) <= @EndTime
    )
  )
  OR (
    @EndTime > @StartTime
    AND CONVERT(time, r.CreateDate) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime  
  )
)

Lots of good logic practice there.
